# How to graph ARIMA forecasts vs past values in R

Tags: r, forecasting, data-visualization, arima

I have performed an ARIMA model and I am happy with my results. Now I am trying to show that my forecast is good. Is it possible to create a graph that shows the forecast vs past values?

What I am looking for is it possible to back-forecast the data and but it all in a graph where it compares the actual values with the forecasted values?

Comment: If my answear satisfys your needs you can accept it, by pressing the check mark sign!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for some feature of the `autoplot` function. In this MWE `y` equals your time series. `y1_1000` your partly time series which you want to forecast. `arma11` equals your ARMA model which you fitted against your time series. `interval_forecast` equals your forecast and `y1001_1100` equals the real values of the time series which you want to compare against your forecast.

[image: Result of the autoplot function]

```
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
set.seed(1)
y <- arima.sim(model = list(ar = c(0.6), ma = 0.5), n = 1100)

y1_1000 <- window(y, end = 1000)
arma11 <- Arima(y1_1000 , order = c(1,0,1))
# with level = 80 one gets the 80% forecast interval
interval_forecast <- forecast(arma11, h = 100, level = 80)
y1001_1100 <- window(y, start = 1001)
autoplot(interval_forecast) + autolayer(y1001_1100, series = "Test")
```

If one wants to know how many observations are not coverd by the interval. One could try something like this:

```
(mean(y1001_1100 < interval_forecast$lower |
y1001_1100 > interval_forecast$upper))
## [1] 0.19
```